# The scroll picker's locked height is huge! Smaller drop down list possibilities?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, scrollwheel

I am writing an app in which I'd like a user to pick from about 25 choices, but each choice is only about 4 letters long. I would like to use the built in scrolling wheel, but the dimensions are just so big. I don't mind if it looks small, and when the user clicks it expands to the full sized wheel selector, but as it is now it takes up half of the screen.

Does anyone know an alternative for a wheel-like selector? I don't want the user to have to see all 25 entries in the list at the same time, but also want to be frugal with my screen real estate. Thanks!

Comment: Label with an edit button and an action sheet?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dropdown

Comment: @Stavash  Thanks for that link to all those drop-down style pickers. Is this the best place for open-source pickers like that? Are there more to be found over the net?

Comment: Yes, there are many more. CocoaControls is a great source. You can also try cocoapods